# How can I pipe the output of a program that can only write to a file (and not to STDOUT)?

Tags: linux, pipe

I'm trying to write something like [Perl Audio Converter](http://pacpl.sourceforge.net/), so I need to be able to decode every relevant audio format to wav (PCM) and then encode wav to every relevant audio format. I'd like to do this in parallel, by piping the output of the decoder directly to the input of the encoder. Most decoders have an option to decode to stdout, but not all of them do. Some insist on outputting to a file.

So my question is, how can I trick a program that will only output to a specified file into using stdout instead? Also, the complementary question: how can I trick a program that requires in input file into reading from stdin?

Would this be impossible because the program might want to seek back and forth within the output?

Incidentally, Perl Audio Converter sidesteps this problem by always using an intermediate wav file, which means that it never does decoding and encoding in parallel, even for formats that support it.

PS: Yes, there's a reason I don't want to just use Perl Audio Converter, but it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, everyone. It looks like `/dev/std*` and `/proc/self/fd/*` and named pipes are all more or less equivalent, and they all do what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, you can give `/proc/self/fd/1` as a "file" output.
That should work for any program that doesn't try to seek in the output.

Some programs do seek in output (e.g. to write summary info at the start of the file once decoding is complete), and this seek will fail with anything other than a real file.

If the program checks the return value of `fseek` or `lseek` (as it should), the program will likely return an error. If it doesn't, it will likely exit successfully, but will create erroneous output (e.g. with incorrect summary info in the beginning, and extra "junk" at the end).

Comment: There's also `/dev/std{in,out}`.

Comment: So to chain two programs together, I could do something like this? `prog1 --outfile /proc/self/fd/1 | prog2 --infile /proc/self/fd/0`

Answer (score 3):

Some OSes, such as Unix variants and the win32 family, support [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). You might be able to use them instead of stdout/stdin.

Comment: If a program takes an output file argument, there's a good chance that it will delete any file with that name and then create its own. Wouldn't that prevent a named pipe from working?

Comment: Most program creating output files does not delete the file first, it just opens it with the CREATE flag and perhaps the TRUNC flag. Which creates the file if it doesn't exist, and truncates its content if it does exist. This works fine for fifos as well.

Answer (score 2):

Make a named pipe.

```
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
```

Instead of doing e.g.

```
echo foo | wc -c
```

you can use it as a file

```
echo foo > /tmp/myfifo &
wc -c /tmp/myfifo
```

(whichever is started first will block until the other end of the pipe is opened)
But you're right, if the program does require an actual file for e.g. seeking, this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pipe and assign output to the pipe